# PrimeNG Full Calendar 11.2 + Angular 11 not working - Cannot find namespace 'FullCalendarVDom'

Tags: angular, primeng, angular11

I created a `strict` fresh project with Angular 11 and I installed PrimeNG 11.2.

I followed the steps here https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/fullcalendar

But as soon as I import these

```
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
```

```
[39m
Error: node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/vdom.d.ts:9:35 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'FullCalendarVDom'.

9 export import ComponentChildren = FullCalendarVDom.ComponentChildren;
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I also tried by turning `strict` to false in tsconfig and angular.json.

Answer (score 2):

I got my answer from the Discord channel of the library.

It seems that 5.x versions are not supported, and they pointed me to use 4.1.0 and that worked.

Bellow you can see the full answer

> What is the FullCalendar version, their latest version has some issues. I think PrimeNG supports 4.1.0 right now, 5.x is not supported. If this is urgent, you may try the official angular wrapper of FullCalendar as well. In the future, we're planning to implement our own Scheduler component and not use FullCalendar.